# Слетает Docker образ причины

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем причина почему после команды из командной строки `docker-compose up -d` docker-machine заново начинает скачивать все для образа и разворачивать вместо того чтобы брать его из памяти. Может у него время стоит или что то там ломается? Я закачал образ, развернул там дамп базы и хочу чтобы он после этой команды стартовал, а не скачивал заново. Периодически это происходит примерно раз в 1,5 недели. Где посмотреть о сбоях? Или это его нормальное поведение?

Windows 8.1 Docker TollBox

> нужно хотя бы начать с того чтоб показать сам docker-compose.yml – zalex

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  db:
    #build: ./postgres
    image: postgres:9.5
    restart: always
    #command: ["postgres", "-c", "log_statement=all", "-c", "log_destination=stderr"]
    command: ["postgres", "-c", "logging_collector=on", "-c", "log_filename=postgresql.log", "-c", "log_statement=all"]
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=example
      - PGDATA=/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg-data
    volumes:
      #- ./data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - pgconf:/etc/postgresql
      - ./logs:/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_log
      - ./data/backup:/opt/demo
  pinba:
    image: pdffiller/pinba
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 30002:30002/udp
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example

  redis:
    image: redis
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379

  pinboard:
    image: pdffiller/pinboard
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    volumes:
      - ./pinboard:/opt/pinboard/config
    links:
      - pinba

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
    hostname: "rabbitmq"
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_USE_LONGNAME=true
      - RABBITMQ_LOGS=/var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit.log
    ports:
      - 15672:15672
      - 5672:5672
    volumes:
      - ./data/rabbit:/data
      - ./logs:/var/log/rabbitmq

  adminer:
    image: adminer
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    links:
      - pinba

  nginx:
    # используем последний стабильный образ nginx
    image: nginx:latest
    # маршрутизируем порты
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    # монтируем директории, слева директории на основной машине, справа - куда они монтируются в контейнере
    volumes:
      - ./hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ..:/var/www
      - ./logs:/var/log/nginx
    # nginx должен общаться с php контейнером
    links:
      - php

  php:
    build: ./php
    volumes:
      - ..:/var/www
      #- ./php/ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d
    links:
      - db
      - pinba
      - redis
      - rabbit
    environment:
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG=serverName=Docker
      #XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=host.docker.internal remote_port=9000 remote_enable=1 xdebug.profiler_enable=1 xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/var/www"
volumes:
  pgdata:
    driver: local
  pgconf:
    driver: local
  pglog:
    driver: local
  mysqldata:
    driver: local

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

То что DOCKER tools будет брать самое последнее при сборке меня устраивает, не устраивает то что всё слетает

похоже слетела машина и каждый раз когда слетает появляется еще одна машина, как этот процесс остановить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: если вы используете latest версию образа, то это нормально, за 1.5 недели могло выйти обновление

Comment: Это надо отключать на уровне docker-machine или что то надо прописывать в docker-compose.yml ?

Comment: Могут быть еще причины кроме этой и где посмотреть

Comment: если проблема действительно в этом, то используйте конкретную версию например node:14.15.3, тогда она не будет перезагружаться каждый раз

Comment: нужно хотя бы начать с того чтоб  показать сам docker-compose.yml

Comment: @zalex добавил - но это же поведение машины, а не то какая версия скачивается

Comment: @ExplodingKitten из за это надписи image: nginx:latest может слетать образ и заново все скачивать?

Comment: Ну смотрите. У вас в php сервисе есть build: ./php там живет Dockerfile. Если у вас в докерфайле, например стоит FROM:  php-fpm:latest , то как вам подсказывает уважаемый @ExplodingKitten действительно может скачиваться обновленный образ. Вопрос все ли образы у вас скачиваются, или возможно только те где latest ? 

С другой стороны я сразу не понял что у вас Windows, а это для меня конечно темный лес, как там работает докер. Может это у него обычное поведение обновлять образы ? х.з.

Comment: @ExplodingKitten напишите пожалуйста ответ, чтобы я мог принять его. Удаление :latest помогло